# multiprocessing Pool hangs when there is a exception in any of the thread

Tags: python, exception, multiprocessing, pool, freeze

I am new to Python and trying a multiprocessing.pool program to process files, it works fine as long as there are no exceptions. If any of the thread/process gets an exception the whole program waits for the thread

snippet of the code:

```
cp = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
cp.read(gdbini)
for table in cp.sections():
    jobs.append(table)
#print jobs
poolreturn = pool.map(worker, jobs)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Failure Message:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cnet-python/default-2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/cnet-python/default-2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 477, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/opt/cnet-python/default-2.6/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 259, in _handle_results
    task = get()
TypeError: ('__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)', <class 'ConfigParser.NoOptionError'>, ("No option 'inputfilename' in section: 'section-1'",))
```

---

I went ahead added a exception handler to terminate the process

```
try:
    ifile=cp.get(table,'inputfilename')
except ConfigParser.NoSectionError,ConfigParser.NoOptionError:
    usage("One of Parameter not found for"+ table)
    terminate()
```

but still it waits, not sure whats missing.

Comment: Looks like ConfigParser has the same problem as SQLAlchemy (exceptions not pickleable), see [Hang in Python script using SQLAlchemy and multiprocessing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785899/hang-in-python-script-using-sqlalchemy-and-multiprocessing). I've reported this issue as [ConfigParser exceptions are not pickleable](http://bugs.python.org/issue13760).

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.2+ this works as expected. For Python 2, this bug was fixed in r74545 and will be available in Python 2.7.3. In the mean time, you can use the `configparser` library which is a backport of the configparser from 3.2+. [Check it out.](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser)

Comment: Was this a big in configparser or multiprocess? (I'm getting the same error with multiprocess, unrelated to configparser)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It happens when a worker process raises a **user** exception which has a custom constructor. Make sure your exception (ConfigParser.NoOptionError in that case) initializes the base exception with **exactly** two arguments:

```
class NoOptionError(ValueError):

    def __init__(self, message, *args):
        super(NoOptionError, self).__init__(message, args)
```

Comment: This exception is from a Python module (ConfigParser) and needs to be fixed there.